# Is the new werewolf spirit sight an automatic identification of Duguthim?

Tags: werewolf-the-forsaken, chronicles-of-darkness-2e

With their new rules werewolves can watch the twilight spirits automatically and see them. Regardless which senses they actually use.

Now my question is though what does that mean if it comes to the Duguthim?

As far as I always understood the Duguthim are different as the Spirit is no longer part of the twilight but instead merged with the host. Do werewolves now automatically see that someone is a Duguthim and how the actual spirit looks like or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think so. Though the Duguthim's physical appearance becomes more and more warped by the spirit the longer it is Claimed, Werewolves can't automatically see one just based on their normal senses. Certain Gifts/Facets do allow for that, and The Storm Lord Siskur-Dah effect specifically grants them the ability to see Claimed (which is enough to suggest to me that they can't otherwise, or it'd be a useless effect).

"The Storm Lord Sacred Hunt grants your character the ability to clearly perceive prey that is possessed, Urged, or Claimed. If your character looks at a Ridden human who is the prey of the hunt, for example, she will see the spirit coiled up within him." pg 310 Werewolf the Forsaken (2e)

Edit: Didn't realize this was from our game!

Comment: Hi lionel and your point is? Even if its from our game it is still a valid question and answer :P